# mysql functionality like 'show processlist' with client code info

Tags: php, mysql

Executing `show processlist;` in mysql shows me what threads are running. Is there way to get information about the code that started the thread?

Example:

```
+--------+------+-----------+--------+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+
| Id     | User | Host      | db     | Command | Time  | State | Info   | code_info         |
+--------+------+-----------+--------+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+
| 123    | db   | localhost | db1    | Query   | 52    | Sen.. | SELE.. | /path/to/file.php |
|        |      |           |        |         |       |       |        | line 1 34         |
+--------+------+-----------+--------+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------------------+
```

My current solution is to put a comment in every single sql statement I execute like this:

```
   /* file: path/to/file.php class: testclass */ 
   SELECT  *
   FROM table
   WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not as the query won't pass any information about PHP to the MySQL server.

I would do the exact same thing that you're already doing and add comments to the query

May I ask what you're trying to achieve from this? I wouldn't have thought that the 'show processlist' syntax would usually be called from PHP.